# Why am I getting a 403 forbidden error on Mac Monterey with PHP 8.0?

Tags: php, apache, macos-monterey

On this Mac I have PHP version 7.4 installed, and my locally hosted sites work fine with it. I installed PHP 8.0, and when I switch to it, I get a 403 error when accessing my sites. Switching back to 7.4, they work fine again. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Mac Monterey version 12.5.1

Site configuration example in my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/my.name/Sites/mysite"
  ServerName mysite.loc
  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
  <Directory /Users/my.name/Sites/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
```

In httpd.conf I have the following line:

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so "Certificate Name"
```

Running the command "sudo apachectl configtest" gives the following result:

```
Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so because module signature matches authority "Certificate Name" specified in LoadModule directive
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
Syntax OK
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You have a couple of issues that may not be related. 1) The `<Directory />` is addressing your whole drive. Its really not necessary and can be a security issue 2) The 2 warnings are because you have either included the `httpd-ssl.conf` file unnecessarily OR included it for the riht reasons but not removed the boiler plate code that comes in that file

Comment: You are also still using Apache 2,2 syntax in what I assume woudl be an Apache 2.4 instance i.e. `Order allow,deny  allow from all`